# near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM sms_restricted WHERE (GROUP BY (thread_id=3) ORDER BY date ASC

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, runtime-error, android-sqlite, runtime

Good day to everyone,

I am having trouble with my program.  I am very new to programming android.  However, not so new to programming itself.  It is a simple IM program that kind of copies what most IM does today.  Go into SMS, get the initial person's information and when you click on it, it brings up the entire conversation.  However, I have noticed a lot of listview solutions and I have created a way for Recycleview to do the same job.  I have looked through hundreds of sites and gotten most of my answers through Stackoverflow here and a few other websites.

However, I am not understanding this one. 
In the program, I have already checked for permission and that is working fine.  No major errors.
Part of the main activity:

This code works in Main activity.

```
Uri uriInbox = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor inbox = getContentResolver().query
         (
         uriInbox,
         null,
         "address IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (thread_id",
         null,
         null
         );

if (cursor.moveToFirst())
   {
   for(int i=0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
       {
       // Get information from the Inbox
       arrContactThreadIDIntent.add(cursor.getString(1));
       arrContactAddressIntent.add(cursor.getString(2));
       arrContactNameIntent.add(cursor.getString(3));
       arrContactTypeIntent.add(cursor.getString(9));
       arrContactBodyIntent.add(cursor.getString(12));   
       // Move to next message.
       cursor.moveToNext(); 
       // this should move to the next row.
       } // end for loop
  }// end if
  cursor.close();
```

However, when I get to the 2nd activity I only pass the thread id along and attempt to duplicate the same query.  Only this time, I just want to pull the sms query by thread_id only and Date ASC.

```
Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor inbox2 = getContentResolver().query
     (
     uriSMS,
     null,
     "GROUP BY (thread_id=" + smsThreadID,
     null,
     "date ASC"
     );

Cursor cursor2 = inbox2;    

// Get the Messages.
if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor2.getColumnCount(); i++) 
       {
       arrThreadID.add(cursor2.getString(2)); 
       arrAddress.add(cursor2.getString(3));
       arrName.add(cursor2.getString(4));
       arrMessage.add(cursor2.getString(13));
       arrDate.add(cursor2.getString(5));
       arrType.add(cursor2.getString(10));
       cursor2.moveToNext();
       }
   }
   cursor2.close();
```

At this point the coding is correct. I started up the program and the 2 names that are listed in the SMS comes up just fine.  I click on the initial person name and crash.  I later ran debug and get the error message.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM sms_restricted WHERE (GROUP BY (thread_id=3) ORDER BY date ASC
```

I know what some of you may say.  "This has already been answered."  However, the answers did not cover if the query is, "sms_restricted"? How do I fix this?  I have already added additional check permission and still the same results.  Or did I miss something...  I got it to work once but not in the 2nd activity.

2nd questions, did I write the query wrong?  Or is there something else underlying the issue.

I hope this will be specific enough for some help.  If not, please let me know.

Please and Thank You.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the `query` is wrong. Replace `"GROUP BY (thread_id=" + smsThreadID` with `"thread_id=" + smsThreadID`.

Your query will then change to:

```
SELECT * FROM sms_restricted WHERE (thread_id=3) ORDER BY date ASC
```

which is what (according to your question) you want :)

Comment: Woot, Thank you very much.  That did the trick.  Now for the million other debugging issue I still have to go through.  By the way, is there some information that covers content resolver a little better when it comes to writing queries?  I already read through Android Developer version and it did not help much...  Please and Thank you again. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know great resources about this. Googling `android Cursor query` or something similar might give you access to great resources

Comment: Awesome, Thanks again for the help. :)  Now I got some reading to do. :D